# Object-oriented web scraping with Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, functional-programming, inheritance, iteration

I usually write function-only Python programs, but have decided on an OOP approach (my first thereof) for my current program, a web-scraper. Here is the working code I wrote which I am looking to have critiqued:

```
import csv
import urllib2

NO_VACANCIES = ['no vacancies', 'not hiring']

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get_source(self):
        self.source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        return self.source  

class HubPage(Page):
    def has_vacancies(self):
        return not(any(text for text in NO_VACANCIES if text in self.source.lower()))

urls = []
with open('25.csv', 'rb') as spreadsheet:
    reader = csv.reader(spreadsheet)
    for row in reader:
        urls.append(row[0].strip())

for url in urls:
    page = HubPage(url)
    source = page.get_source()
    if page.has_vacancies():
        print 'Has vacancies'
```

Some context: `HubPage` represents a typical 'jobs' page on a company's web site. I am subclassing `Page` because I well eventually subclass it again for *individual* job pages, and some methods that will be used only to extract data for individual job pages.

Here's my issue: I know from experience that `urllib2`, while it has its critics, is fast - *very* fast - at doing what it does, namely fetch a page's source. Yet I notice that in my design, processing of each url is taking a few orders of magnitude longer than what I typically observe.

- Is it the fact that class instantiations are involved (unnecessarily,
  perhaps)?
- Might the fact that `HubPage` is inherited be at cause?
- Is the call to `any()` expensive?

Comment: I made an edit to your post, there were a few things which were not related to the code. Feel welcome to review it and rollback the edit, if needed.

Comment: It's sad that I needed to add those two things. But people seem more intent on going around closing valid posts that also help others, than actually contributing value.  It seems the only way to try prevent this is to explicitly state that it is my code, it works etc. etc. Yawn.

Comment: You'll get more acquainted with the scope here as it goes, but mostly it's better to focus on what your code does and how, etc.

Comment: have you done benchmarks versus `requests` module?

Comment: @chicks I am aware of the requests module, but as you can see from my questions, the page-fetching module is not the issue here. It's moreover the scaffolding I have placed around.

Answer (score 2):

## Use top-level functions

Reading URLs from a file and checking each of them for vacancies is done at the top-level of the file. You should enclose this code into functions and put the remaining top-level code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` to:

- separate the intents;
- reuse the code more easily;
- not have random code execution when `import`ing the module.

## Use `filter`

You are only interested in knowing which URL have vacancies. The easiest way to perform that is to:

```
interesting_urls = filter(has_vacancies, url)
```

with the proper definition of `has_vacancies`.

You also only `print 'Has vacancies'` when a given URL has so, letting the user try to figure out which one actually has. You might want to print the URL instead to make your script more usable:

```
print 'Following URLs have vacancies'
for url in filter(has_vacancies, urls):
    print url
```

## Use generators

There is no need to store all the URLs you’ll be checking up-front. Yield them from a generator since only one is processed at a time:

```
def read_urls(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as spreadsheet:
        reader = csv.reader(spreadsheet)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[0].strip()
```

It also allows you to parametrize with the name of the file to read, in case you have several of them.

## Do not force OOP when not required

You are not interested in storing a state about each URL. You just want a simple question answered: *"does this URL points to a page that provide vacancies?"* Thus a simple function will do, for each URL:

```
def has_vacancies(url):
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    return not(any(text for text in NO_VACANCIES if text in source.lower()))
```

See what I did there? This is the exact function we need for the `filter` I introduced earlier.

## Remove extraneous computation

Calling `lower()` on a string has its cost. Calling it once for every piece of text your are looking for in said string is even more costly. You should call it only once after fetching the source of the URL.

Of a lower interest, `any` is converting pieces of text to their truthy value after a test `text in source` already returned `True`. You also store `source`, `self.url`, `self.source` (and, to a lesser extend, `page`) without really needing it. But I’ve shown ways to avoid it.

## Proposed improvements

```
import csv
import urllib2

NO_VACANCIES = ['no vacancies', 'not hiring']

def has_vacancies(url):
    source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().lower()
    return not any(text in source for text in NO_VACANCIES)

def read_urls(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as spreadsheet:
        reader = csv.reader(spreadsheet)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[0].strip()

def check_vacancies(filename):
    print 'Following URLs have vacancies'
    for url in filter(has_vacancies, read_urls(filename)):
        print url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_vacancies('25.csv')
```

## Going further

You might be interested in trying the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to perform text matches, there may be a performance improvement.

Alternatively, the `multiprocessing` module provide a [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) performed in parallel by a pool of workers. You might want to change `has_vacancies` a bit and use that instead of `filter` to increase overall performances.

You may be interested into handling exceptions from `urllib2` so a sudden networking failure or an invalid URL won't crash everything. Something simple can do:

```
def has_vacancies(url):
    try:
        source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print 'Error processing', url
        return False
    else:
        source = source.lower()
    return not any(text in source for text in NO_VACANCIES)
```

Comment: Many thanks. You say, *'Calling  `lower()` once for every piece of text your are looking for in said string is even more costly. You should call it only once after fetching the source of the URL.'* But I *am* only calling it once, am I not?

Comment: @Pyderman My intuition is telling me that `if text in self.source.lower()` will call `lower` for each `text`. Will need to examine compiled bytecode to be sure.

Comment: I see the distinction now, and yes it would certainly appear that `lower() `was being called for every single character in the source.

Comment: @Pyderman Just checked with the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html) by turning the generator expression fed into `any` into a list comprehension and assigning it to a variable… Using `if text in self.source.lower()` will perform a (costly) call to `lower` at each iteration and not work with a cached result of this call.

Comment: Interesting. Still on the matter of speed, it has been suggested that I convert that NO_VACANCIES list to a `set`. Would you agree that this might speed things up further? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181153/why-is-pycharm-suggesting-i-convert-my-list-to-a-set

Comment: @Pyderman Since there is no `in` checks and you are always iterating over all `n` values, there is not much differences by changing the type of container. However, IIRC, tuples and frozensets are somewhat quicker to load. Local variables too (compared to globals) so you might want to use a parameter with a default value. For instance: `def has_vacancies(url, no_vacancies_pattern=('no vacancies', 'not hiring')):`